# How to login remotley to windows from alpine docker image without GUI or SSH

Tags: docker, rdp, alpine-linux

I need to achieve to get an user actively logged into several windows virtual machines from a docker alpine container. I can't use remote desktop, as I have no GUI. I also don't think to really control the Virtual Machines at all, I just need a local user of the virtual machines to be logged in.

How do I achieve that without overcomplicating stuff?

Comment: Improved grammar

Comment: What's wrong with ssh?

Comment: It's very complicated to set up for windows machines (I have 12 machines I would need to setup...). But if it is the only solution, I would go with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone reading this in the future:

I just activated the autologin feature of Windows 10. In that way, I ensure that my machine always automatically logs in with provided credentials.

To acieve that do the following steps:

- Open your registry editor
- Navigate to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
- If one of the following doesnt exist, just create them:

  - Edit "DefaultUserName" to the user you want automatcally to log in
  - Edit "DefaultPassword" to the password of the user you want to log in
  - Edit "AutoAdminLogon" and change value from 0 to 1
- Restart your computer